# Proving 2 matrices have the same trace

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-inverse, traces

I found a problem in my textbook and I have tried solving it, but I had no succes. The problem is:

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices with complex number entries. Given that $AB−BA$ is invertible and $(A−B)^2=I_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix, prove that $tr(A)=tr(B)$ and that $n$ is even. How should I approach this problem? I have tried to actually compute the inverse of $AB−BA$ from $(A−B)^2$ but I had no succes. I can also say that the eignevalues of $A-B$ are $+1$ or $-1$, but how does that help?

Comment: Textbook questions should be asked on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Shthephathord23, welcome to MathOverflow! This site is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. Please have a look at [math.se] to ask general mathematics questions. Check [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/228959) to make sure your post is in good shape. Your question is definitely [off-topic](/help/on-topic) and better deleted here.

Comment: I didn't know that. Sorry. I have tried deleting it but the site does't allow me to. Is it possible to get in touch with a moderator to delete this question?

Comment: the question was answered, and the answer was upvoted and accepted; I would just leave it, it does no real harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call $C=A-B$. Then you have $C^2=I_n$ and $BC-CB$ is invertible. You want to show that $C$ has an equal dimension of $1$ and $(-1)$ eigenspaces, which in turn implies both the equality $tr(A)=tr(B)$ and $n$ being even.

Pick an eigen basis of the space to assume that
$$
C=\left(
\begin{array}{c}I_m & 0\\ 0&-I_k\end{array} 
\right),
~~
B=\left(
\begin{array}{c}B_1 & B_2\\ B_3&B_4\end{array} 
\right)
$$
with the appropriate sizes of $B_i$.
Then
$$
BC-CB=\left(
\begin{array}{c}0 & *\\ * &0\end{array} 
\right).
$$
If $m>k$, then the first $m$ rows are linearly dependent and if $m<k$ then the last $k$ rows are.